# Offloading https to load balancers with Spring Security

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, https, spring-security, load-balancing

Right now, the load balancers handle https and then pass along that https to my web servers. So dealing with https double for each request. What I want to do is completely offload https so my web servers don't have to deal with it.

How do I configure Spring Security and JSP pages given that the web servers think all requests are http? Obviously I'll have to modify the `<intercept-url>` elements of my configuration to have their `requires-channel` attribute always be `http` or `any`. In my JSP pages I'll have to prepend the `<c:url value=''/>` links with a `${secureUrl}` and `${nonSecureUrl}` depending whether the resulting page needs to be https or http. Redirects from controllers need to be modified like this as well... Anything else?

Seems like quite a pain to modify all links in JSP pages to include the scheme and host too. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you terminate SSL at the load balancer then your load balancer should send a header indicating what protocol was originally requested.  For example, the F5 adds X-Forwarded-Proto.

From here you can create custom `ChannelProcessor`s that look at this header instead of looking at `request.isSecure()`.   Then you can continue using `<intercept-url requires-channel="https">` and relative `<c:url>`.

The steps:

1. Subclass [SecureChannelProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/SecureChannelProcessor.html) and [InsecureChannelProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/InsecureChannelProcessor.html) overriding `decide()`.  In `decide()` check the header sent by your load balancer.

   ```
   @Override
   public void decide(FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) throws IOException, ServletException {

     for (ConfigAttribute attribute : config) {
         if (supports(attribute)) {
             if (invocation.getHttpRequest().
                     getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto").equals("http")) {
                 entryPoint.commence(invocation.getRequest(),
                     invocation.getResponse());
             }
         }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then set these ChannelProcessors on the [ChannelDecisionManagerImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.html) bean using a `BeanPostProcessor`.  See this [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor) on why/how to use a `BeanPostProcessor` for this.

Comment: tried the above steps, decide method is not getting called, is there anything else we need to configure?

Answer (score 3):

To complete the great sourcedelica answer, here is the full code :

For Step 1 :

```
@Component
public class SecureChannelProcessorHack extends SecureChannelProcessor {

@Override
public void decide(FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) throws IOException, ServletException {
    for (ConfigAttribute attribute : config) {
        if (supports(attribute)) {
            if ("http".equals(invocation.getHttpRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto"))) {
                getEntryPoint().commence(invocation.getRequest(),
                        invocation.getResponse());
            }
        }
    }
}
}



@Component
public class InsecureChannelProcessorHack extends InsecureChannelProcessor {

@Override
public void decide(FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) throws IOException, ServletException {
    for (ConfigAttribute attribute : config) {
        if (supports(attribute)) {
            if ("https".equals(invocation.getHttpRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto"))) {
                getEntryPoint().commence(invocation.getRequest(),
                        invocation.getResponse());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And step 2 :

```
@Configuration
public class LoadBalancerHack implements BeanPostProcessor {

@Inject
SecureChannelProcessorHack secureChannelProcessorHack;

@Inject
InsecureChannelProcessorHack insecureChannelProcessorHack;

@Value("${behind.loadbalancer?false}")
boolean behindLoadBalancer;

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (behindLoadBalancer && bean instanceof ChannelDecisionManagerImpl) {
        System.out.println("********* Post-processing " + beanName);
        ((ChannelDecisionManagerImpl) bean).setChannelProcessors(newArrayList(
                insecureChannelProcessorHack,
                secureChannelProcessorHack
        ));
    }
    return bean;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Grails supports this as a part of the security plugin. Checkout the bottom section of http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/17%20Channel%20Security.html where they talk about checking request headers, which the LB will set.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = '...'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = '...'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = '...'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = '...'
```