# Redirect 302 loop when force routing HTTP traffic to HTTPS via Spring

Tags: spring, nginx, spring-security, https, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect all traffic hitting HTTP to HTTPS on my application. Nginx is handling generating keys and certificate signing requests.

HTTPS works perfectly when we type it in manually in the browser's address bar. So to force all HTTP requests to use HTTPS we are changing Spring configuration in various ways.

When adding the `requires-channel="https"` attribute to `<intercept-url/>` in our .xml we are getting a 302 redirect loop. We tried declaring the port mappings in a Spring config .xml as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418254/adding-https-support-causes-loop-redirection) but it made no difference to the redirect loop. HTTPS is looping on itself by looking at the network tab in chrome dev tools.

Any help/ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ended up abandoning this approach and doing it from web server (nginx) config instead