# Check the XForwardedProto in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I  have followed the techinical guidance in the below link. But I am not able to get a clear idea how i can configure that in my spring rest framework.

[Offloading https to load balancers with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002272/offloading-https-to-load-balancers-with-spring-security)

My requirement is before the actual request comes to my rest api, it's hitting the Amazon elb. Elb is converting https to http. But I need to check the original request is HTTPS and it's properly converted to HTTP using the ELB.
I have gone through the SecureChannelProcessor and InsecureChannelProcessor.

I am expecting my request should be HTTPS before hitting the ELB and after the ELB it should be HTTP. That validation check should be handled in my REST API Code. END USER REQ ---(https)----> ELB -------(http)--> REST API  in my rest api, I should be able able to check the X-Forwarded-Proto (Or request type) should be https and it's been converted as http in my ELB.

But Not getting a clear idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code.  Explain why it does not work for you and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I am expecting my request should be HTTPS before hitting the ELB and after the ELB it should be HTTP. That validation check should be handled in my REST API Code.

USER REQ  ----->  ELB   ----->  REST API
                 <https>             <http>

in my rest api, I should be able able to check the X-Forwarded-Proto (Or request type) should be https and it's been converted as http in my ELB.

Comment: Please update the question. You can edit questions by pressing the `edit` button direcdtly below the tags.

Comment: Done. Please check it now.