# Infinite loop when serving some urls by https and rest by http

Tags: java, spring, ssl, nginx, tomcat7

I'm trying to get my spring application to work behind Nginx. SSL is terminated on nginx side. All requests from nginx is going over 8080 port to Tomcat. Url's in /profil/ must be secure by ssl, rest url's should not secured. I decided to use "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto" to inform my application about protocol. On application side I have created custom `ChannelProcessors` like there [Offloading https to load balancers with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002272/offloading-https-to-load-balancers-with-spring-security/).

The problem is when I wants to leave https from `https://some.domain.com/profil/` to home page `https://some.domain.com`, then I get infinity loop. There should be 301 redirect to `http://some.domain.com`. It looks like my app can't go outside https. Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT (add log console)**

```
Request 1 (https://some.domain.com/):
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: some.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Referer: https://pkt-ui-ci.pkt.pl/profil/

Response 1:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://pkt-ui-ci.pkt.pl/

Request n loop (https://some.domain.com/):
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: some.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Referer: none

Response n (loop):
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://some.domain.com/
```

**nginx config:**

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
listen 443;
server_name some.domain.com;

root /srv/www/;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;

ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-URI $request_uri;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
       }
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name some.domain.com;

root /srv/www/;

location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-URI $request_uri;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
       }
}
```

**Tomcat server.xml**

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           proxyName="some.domain.com"
           redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost"> 
            <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
                    remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
                    proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
                    protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

**Spring Security config:**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {   
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/profil/").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .requiresChannel()
        .antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/script/**", "/styles/**", "/images/**", "/fonts/**", "/js/**", "/javascript/**").requires(ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.ANY_CHANNEL)
        .antMatchers("/profil/").requiresSecure()
        .anyRequest().requiresInsecure()
    .and()
 //other spring security staff
}
```

**LoadBalancerHack config class**

```
@Configuration
public class LoadBalancerHack implements BeanPostProcessor {

   final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoadBalancerHack.class);

    @Autowired
    SecureChannelProcessorHack secureChannelProcessorHack;

    @Autowired
    InsecureChannelProcessorHack insecureChannelProcessorHack;

    @Value("#{'${behind.loadbalancer}'}")
    boolean behindLoadBalancer;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (behindLoadBalancer && bean instanceof ChannelDecisionManagerImpl) {
            LOGGER.info("********* Post-processing " + beanName);

            ((ChannelDecisionManagerImpl) bean).setChannelProcessors(newArrayList(
                    insecureChannelProcessorHack,
                    secureChannelProcessorHack
            ));
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

**InsecureChannelProcessorHack class**

```
@Component
public class InsecureChannelProcessorHack extends InsecureChannelProcessor {

    @Override
    public void decide(FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) throws IOException, ServletException {

        for (ConfigAttribute attribute : config) {
            if (supports(attribute)) {
                if ("https".equals(invocation.getHttpRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto"))) {
                    getEntryPoint().commence(invocation.getRequest(),
                            invocation.getResponse());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SecureChannelProcessorHack class**

```
@Component
public class SecureChannelProcessorHack extends SecureChannelProcessor {

    @Override
    public void decide(FilterInvocation invocation, Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) throws IOException, ServletException {

        for (ConfigAttribute attribute : config) {
            if (supports(attribute)) {
                if ("http".equals(invocation.getHttpRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto"))) {
                    getEntryPoint().commence(invocation.getRequest(),
                            invocation.getResponse());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your nginx config is listening at 443 while your tomcats server.xml is configured for https at 8443...Same for port 80 and 8080. Change them first,.

Comment: @WeareBorg no it's not, only reference is `redirectPort="8443"` which is not the port bound to, only the port the container will redirect to when an appropate security requirement is needed.  There is only a HTTP server on port 8080 in the TC config.

Comment: Ok, I might be wrong, not that much idea about nginx, I just saw, so pointed out... :-)

Comment: Myself I would look at TC with nginx using AJP (not HTTP) this should be much simpler to configure.  You can keep HTTP as well if you want.  This removes the need for passing lost info with additional headers.  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nginx+tomcat+ajp&ie=utf-8 and everything kind of works, even HTTPS info.

Comment: Maybe `proxyPort="443" scheme="https"` are needed attributes in the `<Connector>` part ?  http://serverfault.com/questions/172542/configuring-nginx-for-use-with-tomcat-and-ssl  and also https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html ... but really use AJP instead of HTTP for the internal protocol between nginx and TC :)

Comment: @DarrylMiles why proxyPort="443" scheme="https" ? My Nginx talk to Tomcat by 8080 only. For more info I was debug may app and I see only again and again: 12-11-2015 15:26:35,367 [DEBUG] hannel.RetryWithHttpEntryPoint  Redirecting to: `http://some.domain.com/`

Comment: 1st did it fix the matter (maybe remove `proxyName=""` setting while adding the 2 attributes) ?  It is complicated to explain in a comment here.  Your public facing service is HTTPS on port 443.  The servlet API is expecting only TC to be the webserver, but the HTTPS endpoint is actually managed by nginx no TC directly, but the servlet API only sees HTTP on port 8080 so it build redirect based on that.  This is why AJP is just a better servlet proxy protocol as such details are conveyed, it will look and act like a HTTPS connection.

Comment: The AJP module for Nginx is not official and I'm afraid of this. Before Nginx I have tried this approach with Apache (Apache AJP 8009 --> Tomcat AJP 8009) but I have the same problem.  I will try back to Apache with AJP. Thanks for response.