# IIS 7.5 with aws elb problem http to https j_spring_security_check.action

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elb

I have a problem with configuration with was elb to IIS 7.5.
The SSL protocol is shared on elb and we can't take the SSL for configuring into IIS , when I configure the port https of elb that point to HTTP port of IIS.
The problem is that when i logIn the j_spring_security_check.action redirect all in HTTP.
There is a method for force response of j_spring_security_check.action in HTTPS?
I tried with Url Rewrite module but not working for me .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there might be something wrong with settings on the application level.
I am not familiar with Spring Security framework. See this link.
[Offloading https to load balancers with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002272/offloading-https-to-load-balancers-with-spring-security)
Besides, please refer to the official guideline for configuring SSL offloading to build connection between the web server and the ELB.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-windows.html
Here is a discussion about how to set up SSL offloading with the ARR load balance.
https://forums.iis.net/t/1182259.aspx